# Insert variable in Spaw Editor

Tags: php, javascript, editor

```
$sw = new  SPAW_Wysiwyg('txtContent' , stripslashes($descHTML) ,'en' ,'intlink' , 'default' ,'400px' ,'200px' ,'',$spaw_dropdown_data);
$sw->show();
```

and when i am trying to include a variable from outside using javascript like this way -

```
<b style="color:#CC3300">&#8249;</b> 
<a href="javascript:insertVar(document.frmNewsLetter['txtContent'],'[FIRSTNAME]');">First Name</a>
```

using this way i can insert into textarea but not in spaw

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the Spaw objects in Javascript rather than directly modifying its DOM elements.

There should be a global Javascript object named `txtContent_obj` (or something similar to that -- check exactly what you've got with Firebug), which you should be able to manipulate to update the Spaw editor's contents correctly.

You should be able do something along these lines:

```
window.txtContent_obj.current_context.innerHTML = "Lets give this a try";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: function insertVar(editpane,myvar)
{
 editpane.focus();
 
 if (editpane.selectionStart || editpane.selectionStart == '0')
 {
  var selstart = editpane.selectionStart;
  var selend = editpane.selectionEnd;
  
  editpane.value = editpane.value.substring(0, selstart) + myvar + editpane.value.substring(selend);
  editpane.selectionStart = selstart + myvar.length;
  editpane.selectionEnd = editpane.selectionStart;
 }
 else if (document.selection)
 {
  var txt = document.selection.createRange().text = myvar;
 }
 editpane.focus();
}
actually i am using this kind of javascript so what i have to do

Comment: @Ricky - in your example code from the original question, try putting `window.txtContent_obj.current_context.innerHTML` instead of `document.frmNewsLetter['txtContent']`.